# Problems creating jar files

Tags: java, jar

I typically use Eclipse to do all my java programming in and when I use it to test my programs it works great. No problems at all with it so far. My problems are coming in when I try to create an executable jar file. It doesn't matter if I use Eclipse to make it or do it through command, I always end up with the same error of "Could not find the main class: Main" I have followed written guides on it and even some YouTube videos for a visual example. Why is it that it's not able to find the main class?

Comment: Please provide the structure of your JAR file along with the manifest.mf

Comment: What is the exact command line you are using to create the .jar?  Does your class reside in a package?

Comment: A typical mistake is to forget to add a blank line after the 'Main-Class' attribute

Comment: I use "jar cfm Game.jar manifest.txt Main.class" to create the jar file.

Comment: Is Main class in the root package? You need fully qualified class name like com.example.test.Main. Did you check the content of the jar? You can open it with winzip or the like

Comment: When opening up the jar file the Main.class file is inside the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Try changing your manifest filename to 'MANIFEST.MF'**

According to the [online specs for manifest files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest), it expects a specific filename in a specific location.  The jar tool handles the location but if you are giving it 'manifest.txt' it might keep that name which then is skipped by the jar loading mechanism.

```
     The META-INF directory  

        The following files/directories in the META-INF directory are recognized and 
        interpreted by the Java 2 Platform to configure applications, extensions, 
        class loaders and services: 

     MANIFEST.MF
     The manifest file that is used to define extension and package related data.
```

Try [letting Eclipse generate the JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420655/135078).  The Main class should be in a subdirectory that matches the package structure.  Does your Main class have a package?  If not, add

`package test;`

to the top of Main.java, then make sure that the Main.class file gets created as /test/main.class inside the jar.  The MANIFEST.MF can then have a [reference to your Main.class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes) for the [application's entry point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) as follows:

> Main-Class: The value of this attribute defines the relative path of
>   the main application class which the launcher will load at startup
>   time. The value must not have the .class extension appended to the
>   class name.

[EDIT]
Please post the following:
1) the [directory structure of the generated JAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) (using `jar tf foo.jar`)
2) the contents of the manifest from /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
3) the name and package of the class with the static main() method

Comment: I have tried this as well. And now I have tried making an executable jar file in command, eclipse, and net beans, none of which seem to be able to find the main class.